# C -- same method declared in two header

Tags: c, include, hardware

I am new to C programming. I ran into a confusion when I checked to see the declaration of a method. It shows two different header. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you provide an example? How is the function declared? Is it a library function, some external API? Or is it your function?

Comment: @Olaf I think you're being a little pedantic. Obviously they mean function. It's more helpful to simply offer a correction than to pretend you don't know what they're saying.

Comment: @ThePcLuddite I got my answers so it's all good. But it might discourage other people who are simply beginning.

Comment: @ThePcLuddite: Would the corresponding Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)) be sufficient? There is a massive difference between a _function_ and a _method_. Actually you can also have _methods_ in C - without language support, of course. (Hmm, I might change this to "does not support methods". That would be more precise)

Comment: @Olaf There is certainly a difference, but I would hardly call it "massive".

Comment: @ThePcLuddite: Let's call it "fundamental" then. Non-native speakers might not always find the best term. If y function is bound to a data-set (object) or not is quite a difference to me - be it explicitly or implicitly. (And as possibly you know, on SO people often confuse C++ for C or vice-versa. As written, the question could be very well about some C++ code.)

Comment: @Olaf I can't believe you are still onto this. Haven't I gotten enough down-votes and admitted my stupidity?

Comment: @ilaunchpad: That was really not digging in the wound (there are no downvotes currently, btw.). The end of my previous comment should have been in my fist one actually.

Comment: @Olaf I'm not upset that I got grilled. But I do want to tell the geniuses that sometimes people are just thrown in the situation where they don't have enough time to read the books. It might discourage people to ask for help. It's like the situation in school where you don't want to ask question fearing that you might be called stupid.

Comment: "... might be called stupid" It takes two for this. That is the difference between kids and adults. If one feels offended by criticism, SO is the wrong place. For "reading a book": You do not think it helps to use a common terminology? Tscha, dann kann ich ja auch muttersprachlich antworten;-)

Comment: @Olaf I'm not offended by criticism. i got my answers and I'm happy about it.

Comment: Last post: Apparently you did not understand what I mean. I intentionally wrote "If **one** ...". But you did take it (again wrongly) as directed to you. Ok, I'll leave it at this. (Oh, and: please check the timestamps and whom I actually answered with the late post!)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86904/discussion-between-ilaunchpad-and-olaf).

Answer (score 3):

If by "method" you mean "function", then yes, it is. You can declare *anything* as many times as you want, as long as the declaration is *not a definition* and as long as these multiple declarations *agree with each other* (for a function with external linkage).

In the end, all header files get embedded into multiple translation units anyway, meaning that you end up with multiple translation units containing the same function declarations.

But in most cases re-declaring the same function in multiple different places is not something you want to do, since it requires additional maintenance to keep the declarations consistent. The whole purpose of header files is to solve this maintenance problem and let you declare each of your functions only once.

Comment: Which declaration will the method refer to? How will it find the correct one?

Comment: @ilaunchpad: What do you mean by "correct one"? All *declarations* must be identical. So it doesn't matter which one it chooses. And, importantly, only one *definition* is allowed.

Comment: @ilaunchpad: If the declarations are different, then it is not the same method (you can have two methods with the same name if they take a different number or type of inputs in C++, but not C). If they are the same, then it doesn't matter which one it chooses, does it?

Comment: @R_Kapp: This is a C question. There are no "methods" in C. And no, you  can't have two functions with the same name but "different inputs" in C.

Comment: @AnT: Yes, it should be called function, I was simply using the terminology used in the question to be clear.

Comment: Well!! I'm sorry for calling methods. I'm very new to C.

Comment: Somehow, I managed to miss the part of the comment where I meant to indicate you could do that in C++ but not C... fixed that now, thanks.

Comment: @R_Kapp: Using wrong terminology is actually the opposite of "being clear", but leads sooner or later to confusion of the OP.

Comment: @Olaf: Since it was clear what the OP meant, I was just going for consistency.

Comment: @ilaunchpad: Then you should first read a C book. If you know C++, there will certainly be many familar concepts, but the details are sometimes significantly different. If not, the more you should read a book.

Comment: @R_Kapp: That is my point: Functions are called functions **consistently** (including C++, and other procedural languages btw.) as a commonly accepted term; "methods" are something different - also as a well accepted term. Supporting OPs wrong usage might be consistent with his wrong usage of the term, but not the commonly accepted.